# How to display a list of item from server to view via Angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am working on a project, where I have a list of items present at backend. I have to get that list items via get request and display to my view as a list items. (User can select multiple entries from the list). I got the list items from server to my angular controller. For this project I am using Angular material design. How can I display these list items from controller to view via angular material element, which is able to select multiple entries from the list?

Here is a code example,

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('searchService', function($log, $http) {

    return {

        getTaxonomie: function() {
            var promise = $http.get("http://espri-host179:8586/callrec/getTaxonomy")
                .success(function(response) {
                    $log.debug("successfully got Taxonomie");
                    return response;
                    console.log(" i am from service");
                })
                .error(function(error) {
                    $log.error("searchService.getTaxonomie error:" + error);
                    return {};
                });

            return promise;
        }
    };
});
```

I have created a service to get data from server and now i have to add it to the controller and then display to my view. Right now my controller and view are empty because i don't know how to proceed further.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: please provide code, show what you have done so far

Comment: @NitsanBaleli : I have add my service code. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a basic example on how to iterate on data recieved from a factory:

javascript:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataFactory) {
    dataFactory.getData().then(function(res) {
        $scope.people = res.data;
    })
});

app.factory('dataFactory', function($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getData = function() {
        return $http.get('data.json');
    };
    return vm;
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
  {{$index}}: {{person.name}} is {{person.age}} years old
</div>
```

data.json:

```
[
  { "name": "john", "age": 19 },
  { "name": "john2", "age": 20 },
  { "name": "john3", "age": 21 }
]
```

here's an example [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HztZfkiq9Mrx6lTlfs2q?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood this basic example. But still i am not able to achieve what i want. As you can see from my service that getTaxonomy is the end point of backend. I just know from my backend colleague that if i get getTaxonomy "1"then i'll get the list heading and if i get "1.1"and so onwards then i'll get list items.

Comment: As you can see that in your json data you have name and age attribute which holds the data. In my case i have "1", "2"and so on and also "1.1","1.2","2.1","2.2"and so on attribute. And i have to display them as a list, which later user can select items from that list.

Comment: @HarshSoni try and learn from the example, look at the plnkr. also read up on ng-repeat. from this example you will eventually understand how to perform the same operation with a different data structure